# How to shade rows based on group in a CSV file in VS Code?

Tags: csv, visual-studio-code

I'm having a CSV file in VS Code and I would like to shade/color rows based on group in the first column of the file. So, in a file

```
VAR1, VAR2, VAR3
A, 1, 2
A, 2, 2
B, 1, 1
B, 1, 1
B, 2, 3
C, 1, 1
D, 2, 4
```

rows with A and C values should have another shade/color than rows with B and D (easier to read). I know this is possible in MS Excel, but can I do this in VS Code probably using some extension or settings?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the extension [Highlight](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=fabiospampinato.vscode-highlight).

Add this to your `settings.json`

```json
  "highlight.regexes": {
    "(^(?:A|C).*)": {
      "regexFlags": "mg",
      "filterLanguageRegex": "csv",
      "decorations": [
        { "backgroundColor": "#dddddd" }
      ]
    },
    "(^(?:B|D).*)": {
      "regexFlags": "mg",
      "filterLanguageRegex": "csv",
      "decorations": [
        { "backgroundColor": "#ffaaaa" }
      ]
    }
  }
```

Comment: Great, thanks! Is it possible to make this more generic so that it checks alternating groups in the first column?

Comment: @jrara regex does not have memory, or is able to do some calculations, if you can think of a setting specification that allows calculation and tests based on previous match we could implement it